# How to fetch one by one record from couch db

Tags: node.js, npm, couchdb

Just assume, I'm having the 1000 records in my couch database. Need to fetch one-by-one records in nodeJS.

I'm trying to get the record but not able to fetch one by one

Comment: Could you please share snippet you work with?

Comment: Do you mean CouchDB or do you mean Couchbase (and/or Couchbase Sync Gateway)? They are all different things with different APIs, but you have tagged all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP tags include both `couchdb` and `couchbase` which are *not* the same.  I am assuming CouchDB for this answer and so [couchdb-nano](https://github.com/apache/couchdb-nano) fits the bill.

The basic strategy is to get the first document from the [/{db}/_all_docs](http://127.0.0.1:5984/_utils/docs/api/database/bulk-api.html#db-all-docs) endpoint by limiting the results to one document with the `limit` parameter, then leverage the `start_key`, `limit` and `skip` parameters to get the next document.

For example,

```js
const nano = require("nano")("http://user:pass@localhost:5984/");
const dbName = "stack";

// Do the thing
(async () => {
    let processed = 0;
    let total_docs = 0;
    try {
        const db = await nano.db.use(dbName);
        let result = await db.list({ limit: 1 });

        total_docs = result.total_rows;

        while (result.rows.length) {
            if (processDocument(result.rows[0])) {
                processed++;
            }
            result = await db.list({ start_key: result.rows[0].key, limit: 1, skip: 1 });
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
    console.info(`\nProcessed ${processed} of ${total_docs} documents`);
})();

// Returns true of the document was processed, false if skipped.
function processDocument(doc) {
    if (doc.key.startsWith("_design/")) {
        return false;
    }
    console.log(doc.key);
    return true;
}
```